# Variable-length array in C

Tags: arrays, c, declaration, variable-length-array

Is it possible to declare a variable when initializing an array?

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int x;
    int arr[x];
    
    scanf("%i", &x);
}
```

Or perhaps something similar?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `x` needs to have a value before it's used to size `arr`.

Comment: Programs in C are sequential. At a time of `arr` definition it does not know about the future value of `x`.

Comment: Put the `scanf` between the two variables.

Comment: ah ok. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you may write

```
int x;
scanf("%i", &x);
int arr[x];
```

In this case the array `arr` will be a variable size array. The value of `x` shall be greater than 0.

Otherwise in this case

```
int x;
int arr[x];
```

the variable `x` is uninitialized (because it is a variable with automatic storage duration) and as a result the array declaration invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: OP should note that, as written, this is an exploitable stack overflow bug.